# Why pdo_informix is available with php-cli but not with php-fpm?

Tags: php, pdo, informix, fpm

I try to use pdo_informix in a php project, so i compiled the pdo_informix.so file (i'm on mac OS), when i try a phpinfo in a php page served by php-cli i've got a lot of results for the search "pdo" but with php-fpm, i only see the pdo_informix.ini file that is additional ini file but the .so file is not interpreted correctly. I tried to set the environment variables for each user (mine, informix, root, ...) but nothing changes the behaviour.

Does anybody have an idea? Or maybe does anybody know how i could get more logs (almost nothing in apache access and error logs).

Here is my phpinfo on cli and on fpm, i can't post the whole phpinfo due to a 30 000 chars limit but i can add additional pictures if necessary

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on rhel 9. I wasted 2 days to troubleshoot then i found out that selimux was causing the issue. Disable selinux to resolve the problem.